# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/goals'
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
# getting the table rows
new_tests=soup.find_all('tr')
for new_test in new_tests:
    print(new_test.find('a', class_='playerName').text)
```

I get that above named error while trying to get the text format. Though, it works without the .text format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select your elements more specific, cause in the `<th>` tags there is no such `<a>` - Used [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('tr:has(td)')
```

or

```
soup.select('tr:has(a.playerName)')
```

or based on your example, check if your expected element is available:

```
for new_test in new_tests:
    print(new_test.text if new_test.find('a', class_='playerName') else new_test)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/goals'
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')

for new_test in soup.select('tr:has(td)'):
    print(new_test.find('a', class_='playerName').text)
```